# Strange runtime error when using vectors

Tags: c++, debugging, memory-management, valgrind, openmpi

I have this very strange problem with my code at runtime when I'm running it in parallel with mpi:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./QuadTreeConstruction: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001fbf180 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x776d6)[0x7f38763156d6]
./QuadTreeConstruction(_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorImE10deallocateEPmm+0x20)[0x423f04]
./QuadTreeConstruction(_ZNSt13_Bvector_baseISaIbEE13_M_deallocateEv+0x50)[0x423e72]
./QuadTreeConstruction(_ZNSt13_Bvector_baseISaIbEED2Ev+0x1b)[0x423c79]
./QuadTreeConstruction(_ZNSt6vectorIbSaIbEED1Ev+0x18)[0x4237d2]
./QuadTreeConstruction(_Z22findLocalandGhostCellsRK8QuadTreeRK6ArrayVIiES5_iRS3_S6_+0x849)[0x41dbbd]
./QuadTreeConstruction(main+0xa32)[0x41ca49]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfe)[0x7f38762bcd8e]
./QuadTreeConstruction[0x41b029]
```

My code is valgrind clean up to the some errors that are internal to mpi library (I use OpenMpi and I have seen them many times before but they have never been an issue; see http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=debugging#valgrind_clean). I do not have any problem when I am running in serial.

I have been able to track down the problem to a `SIGABORT` system call using gdb and here is the stack when the code breaks:

```
0   raise   raise.c 64  0x7f4bd8655ba5  
1   abort   abort.c 92  0x7f4bd86596b0  
2   __libc_message  libc_fatal.c    189 0x7f4bd868f65b  
3   malloc_printerr malloc.c    6283    0x7f4bd86996d6  
4   __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned long>::deallocate new_allocator.h 95  0x423f04    
5   std::_Bvector_base<std::allocator<bool> >::_M_deallocate    stl_bvector.h   444 0x423e72    
6   std::_Bvector_base<std::allocator<bool> >::~_Bvector_base   stl_bvector.h   430 0x423c79    
7   std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool> >::~vector   stl_bvector.h   547 0x4237d2    
8   findLocalandGhostCells  mpi_partition.cpp   249 0x41dbbd    
9   main    mpi_partition.cpp   111 0x41ca49
```

This sounds like a memory corruption but I have absolutely no clue what is causing it. Basically the code breaks inside a function that looks something like this:

```
void findLocalandGhostCells(){
    std::vector<bool> foo(fooSize,false);

    // do stuff with foo; nothing crazy -- I promise

    return;
}
```

Anyone has any idea what I should be doing now? :(

Comment: you probably are doing something crazy :(

Comment: indeed I was doing something crazy ... but crazier is the problem was with another array where I was accessing elements out of range and I have no idea why the code was breaking here!

Comment: If you access memory out of range, and especially writing to it, you overwrite some other memory. It seems that in your case you might have overwritten the memory of the vector `foo`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think that's what was causing the problem since the location of memory corrupted pointer was changing to different objects between runs  ...

Answer (score 1):

If you are quite sure that vector operation itself is correct and non-crazy, try tracing the members of your vector step by step. It's possible that some of your other operations corrupted your memory blocks of vector. For example, a memcpy that invaded memory of vector.